# Linear transformation on matrices | $T : M_{2,1} \to M_{2,3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> $$T : M_{2,1} \to M_{2,3}$$
> $$T\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&3\\4&1&5\end{bmatrix}$$
> $$T\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}6&1&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
> $$ Find:T \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

The linear transformation $T : M_{2,1} \to M_{2,3}$ can be consider equivalent to the multiplication of the following matrices -

$$M_{2,1} \times A_{1,3} = M_{2,3}$$

But $M_{2,1}$ is a rectangular matrix, so its inverse can't be calculated. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Find $T((0,1)^T)$. Why are you trying to find the inverse?

Comment: Use linearity—if you can write $(0,1)^T$ as a linear combination of $(1,0)^T$ and $(1,1)^T$, then you can find $T((0,1)^T)$, which is all you need since $T((x,y)^T) = xT((1,0)^T) + yT((0,1)^T)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = 
x \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + y \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} =
(x - y) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + y \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Then apply $T$ on both sides.